# Acronym heading not appearing if all acronyms are categorized

Tags: glossaries

I would like to include a list of acronyms in my document -- since there are many acronyms, I have subdivided them. However, if I subdivide all of them, the acronym heading does not appear. The following MWE is not perfect but it illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[xindy={glsnumbers=false}, nonumberlist, nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\newglossary{countries}{gls1}{glo1}{COUNTRIES}
\newglossary{cities}{gls2}{glo2}{CITIES}
\newglossary{universities}{gls3}{glo3}{UNIVERSITIES}
\newacronym{t}{T}{TEST}
% COUNTRIES
\newacronym[type=countries]{f}{F}{France}
\newacronym[type=countries]{uk}{UK}{United Kingdom}
% CITIES
\newacronym[type=cities]{lon}{LDN}{London}
\newacronym[type=cities]{par}{PAR}{Paris}
% UNIVERSITIES
\newacronym[type=universities]{ens}{ENS}{\'{E}cole Normale Sup\'erieure (Paris)}
\newacronym[type=universities]{icl}{ICL}{Imperial College London}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=ACRONYMS]
\setglossarysection{section}
\printglossary[type=countries]
\printglossary[type=cities]
\printglossary[type=universities]

%\acrfull{t} $1$: \acrfull{ens} is in \acrfull{par}, \acrfull{f}.
\acrfull{ens} is in \acrfull{par}, \acrfull{f}.

%\acrfull{t} $2$: \acrfull{icl} is in \acrfull{lon}, \acrfull{uk}.
\acrfull{icl} is in \acrfull{lon}, \acrfull{uk}.

\end{document}
```

If I however uncomment the two lines containing `\acrfull{t}` the acronym heading appears because `\newacronym{t}{T}{TEST}` is not categorized by type.

I tried to read through the documentation but I am none these wiser. Why is this happening? In my document, all acronyms are categorized, so I would like the heading to appear in that case. Is it even possible?

Comment: The easiest would be to just put `\chapter*{ACRONYMS}` instead of the first `\printglossary` I guess?

Comment: Thank you, @Marijn! I thought about that but I wanted to do it "the right way" because surely there must be a way to do it using `\printglossary`. But my "surelys" are often proven wrong.